# Linux outgoing packet rate

Tags: linux, networking

Is there any way in Linux to measure number of outgoing packets from a machine in a certain amount of time, lets say per second or per minute?

Comment: How about this `netstat -sw`?

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few programs that can do this (most of the good ones are not standard in base distrobution). The one I highly recommend is `iptraf`. Another one is `ntop`. Other than that, writing a custom shell script to cat the output of `ifconfig interface`'s TX packets and have it loop at a desired interval can also do the trick.

Comment: ifconfig is archaic and cannot be reliably parsed. You should use `ip (-o) -s link`.